# WordPress; Code Customize (wp_list_categories)

Tags: wordpress

WordPress is the function code "*wp_list_categories()*"

```
  <?php wp_list_categories(); ?>
```

Screen:

```
  <li class="cat-item"><a href="---" >Cat Name</a></li>
```

**Target:**

```
  <li id="category_filter_dining" style="display: block;" class="">
  <a id="dining" class="category" href="">
  <span class="png_bg category_icon"></span>Cat Name</a>
  </li>
```

How can I do this or this possible?
Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use this code :

```
<?php
  $category_ids = get_all_category_ids();

?>
<li id="category_filter_dining" style="display: block;" class="">
<a id="dining" class="category" href="">
<?php 
 foreach($category_ids as $cat_id) {
  $cat_name = get_cat_name($cat_id);
  echo '<span class="png_bg category_icon"></span>' . $cat_name . '</a>';
 }
?>
</li>
```

`good luck`

Comment: Thank you so much but error:

    `Catchable fatal error: Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string in /home/--/public_html/--/blog/wp-content/themes/v10/sidebar.php on line 17`

Line 17: 

  `echo '<span class="png_bg category_icon"></span>' . $cat . '</a>';`

Comment: sorry , use this :

`<?php
$category = get_the_category(); 
echo $category[0]->cat_name;
?>`

put `$category` in foreach and enjoy

Comment: worked! Show all required but the option to show only one category.

Comment: ok for retrieve all categories use this code : 

`<?php
$category_ids = get_all_category_ids();
foreach($category_ids as $cat_id) {
  $cat_name = get_cat_name($cat_id);
  echo '<span class="png_bg category_icon"></span>' .  $cat_name . '</a>';
}
?>`

Answer (score 2):

Use a custom walker, and you can do basically anything you want

```
$MyWalker = new MyWalker();
$args = array('walker' => $MyWalker);
wp_list_categories($args);
```

Read more about it [here](http://www.ultimatewebtips.com/how-to-customize-wp_list_categories-output/)!

Answer (score 1):

I think what you're looking for is get_categories() - http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_categories .  You can use this to format output of categories.

wp_list_categories() is preformatted into links.